# Angular component not rendered after successful login

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components, angular-router-guards

**Menu Component (should be only visible after a successful login)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public isLoggedIn = false;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {
    this.isLoggedIn = authService.loggedIn();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Menu Component Template**

```
<nav role="navigation" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <ul><li>Admin Menu Item</li></ul>
</nav>
```

**Main Content Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-content',
  templateUrl: './main-content.component.html'
})
export class MainContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Main Content Component Template**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <app-menu></app-menu>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**App Component Template**

I was looking at using `*ngIf` directive to handle the visibility of the menu component, based on whether the user is logged in or not. As seen from above code, the property `isLoggedIn` gets assigned with a boolean value from the `loggedIn()` function.

I think everything is pretty straightforward to this point, but the problem is that the menu component does not show right after a successful login, and I will have to refresh the browser to be able to see the menu. Not quite sure why this is the case here. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: You can use  authService.loggedIn() directly like this 

`<nav role="navigation" *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the loggedIn value in your menu component is only set in ngOnInit.

Use a getter instead, like this:

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public get loggedIn() { return this.authService.loggedIn(); }
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. Yes you are absolutely right. Using a getter does resolve the issue.